# ajax response is failing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to populate a WebGrid in a partial view . Apparently everything is going right no errors no exceptions but **my ajax call is failing.**

My code (Partial view )

```
@using ThisController = MatterDict.Controllers.MatterDictController
@model IEnumerable<MatterDict.Models.MatterDictViewModel>


<div id="wgmatterDict">

    @{
        WebGrid displayGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "wgmatterDict");      
        @displayGrid.GetHtml(columns: new[]
{
displayGrid.Column("LSC_Work_Type", header:"ETHNIC ORIGIN"),
displayGrid.Column("RULE_NO", header:"DESCRIPTION"),
displayGrid.Column("ACT_NO", header:"DESCRIPTION"),
displayGrid.Column("ACTION", header:"DESCRIPTION"),
displayGrid.Column("OPEN_FLAG", header:"DESCRIPTION"),
});
    }
</div>
```

I am getting the result in the Model and this runs as expected .

My Ajax script

```
 $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ WorkType: lsc_WorkType, Rule: rule, Act_No: act_No, ActionDesc: action }),
            type: "POST",
            @*url: '@Url.Action("getQueryResult")',*@
            url: '@Url.Action("DisplayPartial")',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $("#wgmatterDict").html(result)
                alert("successful");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("unsuccessful call ");
            }
        });
```

This is giving an alert :Unsuccessful call

My controller

```
public ActionResult DisplayPartial(string WorkType,int? RuleNo,int? Act_No,string ActionDesc)
        {
            return PartialView("DisplayPartial", getQueryResult(WorkType, RuleNo, Act_No, ActionDesc));
        }

[HttpPost]
       public IEnumerable<MatterDictViewModel> getQueryResult(string WorkType, int? RuleNo, int? Act_No, string ActionDesc)
       {
           IEnumerable<MatterDictViewModel> result = newOps.getQueryResult(WorkType, RuleNo, Act_No, ActionDesc);
           return result;
       }
```

I am using 2 models could you suggest if there is a better way to achieve this.
Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: I think your `dataType` should be `html`, change that and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @ramiramilu , I made the changes that you suggested and now I am not getting the error message but the data is still not binding with the webgrid on the partial view .

Comment: Have you debugged the flow? And did you got any valid HTML in response? Try to make HTML to empty first and then fill with result like this - `$("#wgmatterDict").html(''); $("#wgmatterDict").html(result);`. let me know if you still face the problem.

Comment: @ramiramilu I solved it. I was not binding the webGrid properly. Thanks for you first answer.

Comment: that solved my fist problem so I guess yes..and thanks